# Expanding CSS Grid Rows Vertically

Tags: css, reactjs

### issue

I'm trying out CSS Grid (through React styled components), and have a grid with two columns (one row). The cell of the second column itself has a grid with three items spread over two rows. Please see the image for reference.

### question

How do I get the `some code` block (`OutputContainer`) to be 100% the height of the enclosing block (the row of `OutputGrid`)? Using `height: 100%` seems to have no effect.

Here's the relevant code:

```
const Grid = styled.section`
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 200px;
`;

const OutputGrid = styled.section`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 1fr;
`;

const OutputContainer = styled.section`
  grid-column: span 2;
`;
```

And here's a sandbox with a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/409ozox509

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/v3pv00m6r0) work? I give the the `Card` enclosing the `CodeBlock` `height: 100%` and the black background. Please mark "correct answer" if it solves your problem.